# write the errors into a specified file

Tags: rspec

**How to write the errors(as follow) into a specified file after the test.**

```
Failures:

1) Create should be successful
Failure/Error: unit_ship.should be_valid
expected valid? to return true, got false
# ./spec/models/unit_ship_spec.rbin `block (3 levels) in '
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ rake spec > output.txt
```